# How to Calculate the Max Value per Day in R

Tags: r

I have the following sample dataset:

```
count date
1   11/25/16
2   11/29/16
3   11/30/16
4   12/4/16
5   12/7/16
6   12/8/16
7   12/9/16
8   12/10/16
9   12/11/16
10  12/12/16
11  12/13/16
12  12/17/16
13  12/17/16
14  12/18/16
15  12/19/16
16  12/20/16
17  12/20/16
18  12/20/16
19  12/20/16
20  12/20/16
21  12/21/16
22  12/21/16
23  12/21/16
24  12/21/16
25  12/21/16
26  12/22/16
27  12/22/16
28  12/22/16
29  12/22/16
30  12/22/16
31  12/23/16
32  12/23/16
33  12/23/16
34  12/23/16
35  12/23/16
36  12/23/16
```

I would like to calculate the maximum count for each date. Please note that the final value will not always be the largest in my real dataset. Ideally my output should not have any duplicates.

Comment: Use `aggregate` and the function `length`

Comment: do `table(data$date)`

Comment: Could you expand on the aggregate function? Seems like that is the way to go

Comment: `aggregate(.~date,data,length)`

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` way of doing this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

#Sample data set
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(x = sample(1:10,20,replace = T),
       y = sample(ymd("2018-01-01") + days(0:5),20,replace = T)) %>%
    arrange(y)


df %>%
    group_by(y) %>%
    dplyr::filter(x == max(x)) %>%
    distinct(x,.keep_all = T) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
      x y         
  <int> <date>    
1     5 2018-01-01
2    10 2018-01-02
3     9 2018-01-03
4    10 2018-01-04
5     8 2018-01-05
6    10 2018-01-06
```

Answer (score 0):

`order` your dataframe , then we drop `duplicated` by date column

```
dt=dt[order(-dt$count),]
dt=dt[!duplicated(dt$date),]
dt
   count     date
36    36 12/23/16
30    30 12/22/16
25    25 12/21/16
20    20 12/20/16
15    15 12/19/16
14    14 12/18/16
13    13 12/17/16
11    11 12/13/16
10    10 12/12/16
9      9 12/11/16
8      8 12/10/16
7      7  12/9/16
6      6  12/8/16
5      5  12/7/16
4      4  12/4/16
3      3 11/30/16
2      2 11/29/16
1      1 11/25/16
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `which.max()` and `group_by()` function:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarise(MaxCount = count[which.max(count)])
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  date       MaxCount
  <date>        <int>
1 2018-01-01        5
2 2018-01-02       10
3 2018-01-03        9
4 2018-01-04       10
5 2018-01-05        8
6 2018-01-06       10
```

Sample dataset (edited from @Yifu Yan):

```
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(count = sample(1:10,20,replace = T),
             date = sample(ymd("2018-01-01") + days(0:5),20,replace = T)) %>%
  arrange(date)
```

Comment: I get an error: Error in count[which.max(df_test3$Volume)] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: It seems like you're not using the sample dataset. Could you `dput()` your dataset? in addition, I would assume that the `str()` of your dataset is different.